# Deployment project: Read a setup variable from registry

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, registry

I have a setup project in VisualStudio 2005.

User is invited to fill-in the server address that will be stored in a registry key.

Now, I would like that if the user reinstalls this project, that the old server name be proposed by default as value in the setup interface.

Is is possible to keep the ancient registry key value, to propose it in a new setup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just don't remove the key when you uninstall the program.  Which means don't save your key where the application settings thing saves i.e. create the key yourself.  You'll also want to look into whether you want this key for all users or one for each user and the permissions that your choice affects.

Comment: heh. leaving the key is OK, now the hard part is to read it in setup interface...